# Permissions in SQL Server 2016

Tags: permissions, sql-server-2016

In UNIX (and, if my memory is not betraying me, in Linux too), there is a mechanism through which execute permission is given to users (that cannot access other files) but the program itself runs with different credentials, such that the same files the invoking users cannot access, the user of the program can.

Is there any similar (or equivalent) mechanism that would allow a DB-defined user only to execute a specific procedure and nothing else, while the same procedure would have permission to invoke any other procedure within the schema and, if needed, also access other DBs?

Answer (score 0):

If you grant permissions to user to execute specific procedures then user will only be able to execute those procedures. Inside those procedures you can use same schema objects or call other procedures within same schema (called "ownership chaining") or other schema if that other schema is owned by same owner.

If needed, you can use "Execute As" for stored procedures so that user rights inside procedure are different from user that calls those procedures. That gets tricky in some more complex scenarios (e.g. dynamic SQL).

It gets more complicated if you want to call procedures from other database. In that case would recommend using certificates and procedure signing (Erland Sommarskog [blog](http://www.sommarskog.se/grantperm.html#certcrossdb) is execelent).